# customize css file in acumatica to change form color

Tags: css, customization, acumatica

How can I customize CSS file in acumatica that reflects changes on the website and not just locally.

I couldn't find css code in the customization tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Style configuration can be set in the 'Site Preference' page.

These settings should be visible from external access but you have to make them per company:
[image]

To make more complex changes, you have to manually edit the skin in your website folder. These are in the 'App_Themes' sub folder of your Acumatica instance. Acumatica ships with two themes 'Default' and 'Indigo', default being the one applied on new blank instance. The site preference page 'Interface Theme' field determines which theme is applied.

If you want to modify Form style, first open the 'Container.skin' file and locate the PXFormView component:
[image]

Here I'm using FormContent as an example, this is the name of the CSS element.
You can edit the CSS element in the '00_Controls.css' file from the same folder:
[image]

I change it to fully saturated green #00FF00, when refreshing the Acumatica Website, forms will apply that style:
[image]

For a more complete solution, you can build your own Interface Theme as per the instruction presented here:
http://adn.acumatica.com/blog/acumatica-customization-theming-white-labeling/

Comment: Where can I find the website folder that updates the changes automatically?

I have downloaded the Website Source code from the Inspect Element Tab...but making changes to files in there doesn't update the website.

Comment: On the server where the website is hosted, execute IIS manager program 'inetmgr.exe'. In the left side tree view, find your website name, right click on it and select 'Explore' from the menu. This will open the directory where App_Themes is located. You have to edit the file on disk like any normal Windows text file, not in your browser.

Comment: It worked!

Thank you for you quick and perfect response!

Comment: How can I change the background color of the Forms only for specific Screens?

Comment: You would have to add JavaScript to that page using a customization and set the style explicitly because Acumatica has only 1 style for forms and pure CSS doesn't allow to apply styles based on content. Adding JavaScript to Acumatica pages is not officially supported and your changes might break when we release a new version. However I think it's the only way to achieve styling per page.

Comment: You can ask another question about it as it's quite a different way to go at it. It would likely require a programmer to make this change.